# C# .net core check if os is windows with process directive

Tags: c#, .net-core

Is there is any way to check if the OS is windows before adding "using System.Windows.Forms;".

What i want to do is check if the OS is windows and run Form and if it is not run normal console,so if it's (linux) i dont want to compile "System.Windows.Forms" and to completely ignore the "Form1.cs".

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Environment.OSVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I would suggest having two apps. The first is a .NET Core that runs on all platforms. Then it can launch the Windows specific app based on `OSVersion`. _It can't be (easily) done in one app since compilation is done on **your** machine, not the final target machine._

Comment: @mjwills thank you, i already done that but i thought maybe there is better way to do it

Comment: No there is not. Not easily anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```
System.Environment.OSVersion
```

Comment: This doesn't allow you to specify whether to add a `using` line though